# Show that if $M$ is an invertible $R$-module, then $M^{-1}=\left\{ a \in K : am \in R \ \forall m \in M \right\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $R$ be an integral domain with the field of fractions $K$. Suppose $M \subseteq K$ be an $R$-module. Show that if $M$ is an invertible $R$-module, then $M^{-1}=\left\{ a \in K : am \in R \ \forall m \in M \right\}$.

I'm having a trouble showing that if $N \subseteq K$ is any $R$-module such that $MN=R$, then $M^{-1} \subseteq N$. If $M, N$ are just ideals in $R$ then it's easy ($M^{-1} = M^{-1}R=M^{-1}MN=RN=N$), but this is not useful here because $M$ is a fractional ideal.

Comment: What step of that derivation do you think needs $M$ and $N$ to be ideals in $R$?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey I didn't mean $M, N$ need to be ideals in $R$, which is not true in general.  Maybe I should have said this is easy to show if we assume $M^{-1}$ and all of $N$ are in $R$. Anyway it's not really helpful to prove the statement.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I meant.  Why do you think that $M^{-1} = M^{-1}R=M^{-1}MN=RN=N$ is not valid in general for fractional ideals?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Oh okay, now I see. I just thought $M^{-1}=M^{-1}R$ is not true in general. Actually it holds. Thank you!